# what is the difference between these two buzzers?

Tags: piezo-buzzer

I am looking for a 5v buzzer and I saw a chinese pack of 24 for 9 dollars on Amazon 
[https://www.amazon.com/tatoko-Electronic-Magnetic-Continuous-Arduino/dp/B07QBHPG2X/ref=sr_1_17?keywords=5v+buzzer&qid=1573580272&sr=8-17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QBHPG2X)

And there is a pui audio buzzer, the one costs over 1 dollar.
https://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/665-AI1223TWT5V5R

which is better? is there any difference I would find in terms of sound loudness? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't link to Amazon ads which will die and render your question useless to future readers. Please add the images and essential specifications into your question so that your readers don't have to follow two additional links to understand what you are asking. Hit the *edit* link below your question ...

Answer (score 1):

Both are 2300 Hz, and both are 85dB (i.e., same loudness) .  the Amazon listing makes it clear that it will activate with a DC 5V signal.  The mouser part has a poor data sheet, and it's less to me whether it wants a DC signal or a 2300 Hz sine wave to make it work, though I can convince myself that it works with a DC signal from the "operating voltage range" parameter on the pdf datasheet.

Comment: I think they don't expect anyone to drive a bipolar sine-wave through those due to the complexity and the mundanness of the applicaiton. Just slam a 5V unipolar square wave through it at 2300Hz.

Comment: So why do you think there is a price difference, I used before cheap buzzers on 2 boards, one of them i used directly after soldering it gave me good sound and still, while the 2nd board I kept it stored for 3 months and when I used it the buzzers gaved a very bad high pitch scream sound, why do you think this happened?

Comment: @user233061 lower overhead of an Amazon marketplace vs that of Mouser, a real distributor of electronic parts.

Comment: @ScottSeidman okay, and the second part of the question, what do you think caused some of the buzzers to give bad screaming sound?

Comment: @user233061 No way of knowing.  I suggest asking, with more detail about the situation, in a different question.

Comment: @ScottSeidman okay thank you

Comment: @DKNguyen "they" will sell you whatever you want to buy.  If you search for buzzers in a big distributor, many will not have driver circuitry built in.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/audio-products/alarms-buzzers-and-sirens/157?k=buzzer, which I got to by searching for "buzzer" and clicking the alarms, buzzers, and sirens option.  the whole first default page is "transducer, externally driven".

Comment: oh-- I see, your issue was "sine wave"  -- sorry

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry I didnt understand, what does "driver circuitry built in" mean?

Comment: @user233061 I didn't say that, but it just means that some buzzers are more than "just a speaker". FOr example, you just apply power, DC power to them and they make the waveform themselves to make a sound.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I never said anything about having a driver built in...